# ¿Cómo generar slug automáticamente desde un campo y guardarlo con Class Based Views?

Tags: python, django

Tengo mi modelo que ya genera en el admin un slug dependiendo de que título se coloque en el campo

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    [...]
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Cuando el usuario tenga la oportunidad de hacer el formulario y guardar una nueva película, el slug se genere automáticamente y se guarde en el campo, como se hace con `self.request.user`, este es mi view

```
 class MovieCreate(CreateView):
    model = Movie
    form_class = MovieForm
    success_url = 'Movie:list'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(MovieCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Gracias a quien pueda ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es directamente con el método save() de la clase Movie.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Movie(models.Model):
    # model info
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```